# Invoke grid view on product "list"

Tags: magento-1.8

I am using the following code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

how would I use the "grid" view of this template? In a previous question here someone told me to use 
`{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" products_count="5" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}`

however, this doesn't seem to let me choose a specific category to display.

To wrap up I am essentially trying to use the grid view with a specific category. I also don't want to set the default view to grid I would like it to remain list on the category pages.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to create your own template that only has the grid code from the list.phtml. This way you simply need to update what template to use and have no other code to change.

The other way you will have to investigate how magento deals with the grid and list views. This happens not directly in the `catalog/product_list` block but in the toolbar. Here there should be getters and setters for the view mode.

The template itself uses the check:

```
<?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
```

Where `getMode` simply gets the current mode of the toolbar.

```
public function getMode()
{
    return $this->getChild('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
}
```

The toolbar uses the data under key `mode` to the current mode. So technically it can be set via the get parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Okay i found it. Change folling line

```
<?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
```

to

```
 <?php if(true): ?>
```

Now my startpage have only List mode.